# 5 LED light display

Tags: led

I needed to have a simple circuit designed for a 5 LED light display ran off a 12 Volt battery, with an inline switch.   The LED's are 3 volt, 20 ma.  I needed to know what size battery I needed (current wise)  Fry's sells a 12 volt battery, that is a 1.4 A.  Would that work?   Also I would need to know the current limiting resistor size.  searched for something similar with search engine, but could not find.  Any info would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!  Dana

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f96QqV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 5 x 3 V LEDs on 12 V supply.*

R1 needs to drop 6 V at 20 mA so we use Ohm's Law and get \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {6}{0.02} = 300~\Omega\$. 330 is the next standard value.

R2 needs to drop 3 V and by the same method it works out at 150 \$\Omega\$.

- The total current drawn by this circuit is 20 + 20 = 40 mA.
- The *energy* consumed in one hour will be \$I \cdot t\$ = 40 mAh (milli-amp-hours).

Decide how many hours you want the battery to last and you can then work out the Ah capacity required.

e.g. 40 mA for one week (168 h) gives 40 mA x 168 h = 6,720 mAh or 6.7 Ah. In this case I would go for a 12 V, 10 Ah battery for some safety margin.